# 2013 - SP365: Adding Custom List to AppWeb in a SharePoint-Hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am studying sample code from Jeremy Thake (Microsoft's Senior Product Marketing Manager - Pro Developer Audience) to learn more about app development. [LINK](http://www.jeremythake.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/UbertTaskListAngularApp1.zip)

In his Visual Studio 2013 solution, he has added a list to the project and he put it at the root of his solution. Since my app will have multiple lists, I wanted to organize the solution better by moving his list into a Data folder.

What I can't find out after many Google searches is what I would have to change to make that move -- there isn't any mention of the /Tasks (the name of his list) in the manifest or config.

Can I just move it and Visual Studio will figure out that it's now in the Data folder?

Comment: Link to his sample code?

Comment: http://www.jeremythake.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/UbertTaskListAngularApp1.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the URL for the list when you create it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="Contacts" 
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" 
                TemplateType="105" 
                FeatureId="00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105" 
                Url="Data/Contacts" 
                Description="">

  </ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

[image]

Comment: so I can move his and edit the URL and all will work?

Comment: I don't think you can change the URL after the list has been created. I think you'd need to create a new list with the desired URL, move the items from the old list to the new list, and then delete the old list